# How can i make a blade out of plane like in the tutorial?

Tags: modeling

In the screenshot on the right it's how the blade should look like from the tutorial video. On the left is what i have down so far.

When i select the left bottom corner vertice and then on the left menu click on Translate when i change the x or z i'm not getting nothing even close to this.
In my model it's like extrude it.

[image: Blade]

This is the tutorial: [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ryJ_xG3WeLw&t=1113s)

And he make the blade on minute 22:24

Comment: You are in face selection mode, switch to vertex in the 3D view header buttons at the bottom.

Comment: Press *Ctrl+Tab* and then *V* or choose the *Vertex* from the list.

Comment: Can someone show me please some clip animation here how to do it what keys to click and how much units/values to change each vertex ? I changed the mode to vertex but i can't make the shape. The plane mesh after created it and changed rotation and scale is: Rotation: X = 0.007 Y = -0 Z = 1 and Scale: X = 0.300 Y = 0.780 Z = 0.300 and Dimensions: X = 0.601 Y = 1.560 Z = 0.000

Comment: When i move the selected vertex in edit mode it's moving too much to the right so i'm using Shift when moving so it's moving it in small values but not good enough so i tried to set the Y on my own in Translate. Changed it to 0.016 but not sure if it's right and what to do next.  I select the vertex to move by clicking on the left bottom corner point so it's selecting that point and not the whole vertex.

Comment: That should be quite simple - press Ctrl+coma on the keyboard, switch selection mode to vertices with Ctrl+Tab as is already stated, select bottom vertex, move as desired by X axis (press G, then X), deselect it, select the second from bottom vertex, move a bit less than previous one. Done.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you should use the bevel tool. Switch to edge selection mode and select the edge you want to add a smooth edge too. Then click cntrl+B, you can change the size by moving your mouse up and down, you can also make it smoother with the scroll wheel.

Is this what you want?
[image]

Comment: Bevel won't give the result from the right screenshot, instead it will increase amount of geometry and create Ngons. Just moving 2 vertices is enough

Comment: @MrZak He wants you to play around with the vertices.